# I am not able to get response printed back to text area

Tags: javascript, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am using chatGPT api to make any chrome extension which works in any input area where u have to write help: your question; and the chatGpt respond back to you in same input area. Now the problem is that I created a content.js file for that and install it as chrome extension and whenever i am typing in input area help: some prompt ; it is giving error

console log : `Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}body: (...)bodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: ""type: "cors"url: "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"[[Prototype]]: Response`

Error : `content.js:52 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json') at content.js:36:34`

The line which is giving error :  `.then((response) => response.json())`

This is my whole code :

```
// Define a function to show help prompts
   function showHelp() {
// Get the current input or textarea element
   var activeEl = document.activeElement;
// Get the user's command from the input or textarea element
   var inputText = "";
   if ("value" in document.activeElement) {
   inputText = document.activeElement.value.trim();
   } else {
   inputText = document.activeElement.innerText.trim();
   }
   var command = inputText.substr(
   inputText.indexOf("help:") + 5,
   inputText.indexOf(";")
   );
// Call the OpenAI API to generate a response based on the user's command
   fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
   method: "POST",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization:
    "Bearer API-key(I removed it )",
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{"role": "user", "content": command}],
  temperature: 0.7,
  max_tokens: 256,
  n: 1,
  stop: "\n",
  }),
 })
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  var responseObj = JSON.parse(data);

  // Access the generated text from the response object
  var generatedText = responseObj["choices"][0]["text"];

  // Do something with the generated text, such as display it on the page
  if ('value' in document.activeElement) {
    document.activeElement.value = generatedText;
  } else if ('innerText' in document.activeElement) {
    document.activeElement.innerText = generatedText;
  } else {
    console.error('Error: could not set input value');
  }
})
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
// Listen for changes in the input or textarea element's value
   document.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  // Get the current input or textarea element
  var activeEl = document.activeElement;
 // Get the input or textarea element's value
  var inputText = "";
  if ("value" in document.activeElement) {
  inputText = document.activeElement.value.trim();
  } else {
  inputText = document.activeElement.innerText.trim();
  }
 // Check if the input or textarea element's value end with ";"
  if (inputText.trim().endsWith(";")) {
 // Call the showHelp function
  showHelp();
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is breaking your promise chain:

```
.then((data) => console.log(data))
```

`console.log` doesn't return anything, so this is resolving to `undefined`, and then you try to dereference `undefined`:

```
.then((response) => response.json())
```

Either *return* `data` from the first one, or combine the two:

```
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  return data.json();
})
```

Comment: now giving error  'SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at content.js:35:30' at '.then((data) => {
  var responseObj = JSON.parse(data);' @david

Comment: @Prashantshekhar: You can remove the `JSON.parse()` operation.  The `.json()` operation *already* parses the result and resolves to the object.  It's not clear why you *expected* a different behavior, but when you encounter errors the first thing you should do is debug and observe the actual data you're using.  When you see that what you have is not a JSON string, it becomes clear that your expectations were mistaken and you don't need to parse the string.